# a randomly moving div using keyframes animations, is it possible?

Tags: css, keyframe

I have seen a question like this, it is the same idea; however the answer on there was using JQuery and I was wondering if there is a way to do this using @keyframes:

I am trying to make a game in which a div speeds up each time it is clicked however I can't find a way for the div to move randomly without any javascript (or frameworks). Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to avoid using JS?

Comment: @AbdulShaikh Not really, I would just like to get used to keyframes.